The "Review History" of the staging ground seems a bit inconsistent
When viewing the review history, it showed me this list:

however, the 2nd item there isn't actually approved as of this writing:

https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78577238
Looking at the review history, it did get "approved", whatever that means since it doesn't appear approved, but then immediately marked for minor edits.

Note that this only seems to happen when you are filtering for approved questions if you are viewing the full history without filtering for specific review actions, it seems to show up correctly.

We had an issue with how we retrieved data in the filtering for that page, yours in particular was related to the fact that a post gets multiple Histories when a reviewer "Approves with Minor Edits", which should be fixed now.
Let us know if anything else pops up, and thanks for reporting! We appreciate the help.
